# Branching a solution that contains unit tests and source control structure?

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, branch

Here is an example of my source control structure in TFS 2010:

```
TFS Project
     Development
          Branches
          Source
          Tests
```

Under my Source directory I have created a directory for my Data Access Layer. The solution is  currently not dependent on any other project outside its own solution. I did this so I could branch just this code. I wanted to avoid having to branch the entire Source folder.

I personally like having my unit tests as part of a solution so I can easily create and run tests against the code without having to go into another solution.

If I put my unit test projects in the same solution as my DAL solution, what is the best way to branch my entire DAL without the unit test project dependencies? Should I create another solution without unit Tests for branching? Should I include the unit tests in the branch after I branch the solution?

Since the Tests are located in the Tests folder, there isn't a way to selectively branch folders in TFS.

How do other users approach this?

Comment: What if you branch all the code but only create a solution file containing the projects you want to work on in your branch?

Comment: @WouterdeKort: I thought about that, but then I have 2 solutions to manage. I suppose I could always have a Branch solution to work from. My only concern is that I lose the benefit of creating / running my tests as part of the solution during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit tests also help to act as documentation for the code and examples of how it behaves and how to use it.

Therefore, if you're branching to change the code's behavior, I recommend branching the unit tests along with the code. That way your documentation and examples are always up to date.

Comment: what is the best way to branch in my situation. Like I said, I cannot selectively branch folders, so would I branch the DAL folder and add the Unit Tests back in?

Comment: If your unit tests are tests over your DAL, yes, copy them back in. You'll need to merge them again when you're done. Just make sure they really are tests over your DAL and not dependent on other code, and the merge should be fine. Curious as to why you don't want to branch your entire source folder anyway, though... isn't the DAL's behavior being driven by the code that uses it?

Comment: The DAL's behavior is autonomous to any other code in my infrastructure. I use a Business Layer / Service Layer to dictate how it is used, however, it is not "driven" by the BL or SL.  I wanted it to remain independent so if the infrastructure did need to change I would only need to Branch my DAL.